# mysql: What is the right syntax for NOT LIKE?

Tags: syntax, mysql

Hi I am trying to show tables with names not like a pattern by mysql is throws an error:

```
SHOW TABLES  NOT LIKE  "tree%";
```

returns:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT LIKE "tree%"' at line 1
```

What is the right syntax?

Thanks Arman.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could use the WHERE clause extension, as in:

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE `Tables_in_<DatabaseName>` NOT LIKE 'tree%';
```

This is supported on MySQL ≥5.0.

Reference:

- [12.4.5.39. SHOW TABLES Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-tables.html).
- [20.28. Extensions to SHOW Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/extended-show.html).

Answer (score 1):

LIKE and NOT LIKE are used with SELECT statements. I don't think this works with the SHOW TABLES command.

Comment: Indeed, found that out just now (MySQL 5.7.27 or thereabouts). See the answer by [@kennytm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698917/1035977) for the correct workaround.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5199), this has been introduced in mySQL 5.0.3. However, people there disagree, and it doesn't work in my 5.1.41 installation, either.

I guess the answer is it's not possible.

Comment: It is, but only with the `WHERE` clause.