# Delete data from all tables but keep the data of one table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to delete the data from all tables but one table in my database. Let's assumme the database is called `my_database` and the table in which data should be preserved is called `my_important_table`, so is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes of course. Are you doing this from the mysql console or a program you want to write

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am using mysql console.

Comment: Then you will have to repeat a `truncate <table>` on each table you want to empty

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I have limited experience with MySQL, so can you provide a link or an answer, and is there any way to create a sort of for loop which a condition that does not delete data if the table is called `my_important_table`? (if you provide any reference I can even provide an answer myself)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out this problem thanks to these questions:

- [Truncate all tables in a MySQL database in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command) (check most voted answer)
- [mysql: What is the right syntax for NOT LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698891/mysql-what-is-the-right-syntax-for-not-like) (check validated answer)

The following command worked properly for me:

```
mysql -u root -p -Nse "SHOW TABLES WHERE \`Tables_in_my_database\` != 'my_important_table'" my_database | while read table; do echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; truncate table $table;"; done | mysql -u root -p my_database
```

The following command is the same as the previous one, but I split it into multiple lines to improve visualization.

```
mysql -u root -p -Nse "SHOW TABLES WHERE \`Tables_in_my_database\` != 'my_important_table'" my_database | \
while read table; do echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; truncate table $table;"; done | \
mysql -u root -p my_database
```